# mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given

Tags: php, mysqli

```
/*connection file*/
    function connect(){
            $server = "localhost";
            $user = "xxxx";
            $password = "xxxx";
            $db = "xxxx";
            $connetion = mysqli_connect($server,$user,$password,$db);
    }
```

This is my connection file. i am connect to database using MVC.

```
/*function declaration and insert query*/
    function insert($table,$value){ 
        $fld = "";
        $val = "";
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($value as $k => $v) {
            if($i == 0){
                $fld .= $k;
                $val .= "'" . $v ."'";
            }
            else{
                $fld .= "," . $k;
                $val .= ",'" .$v . "'";
            }
            $i++;
        }
        global $conn;
        return mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO $table($fld) VALUES($val)") or die(mysqli_error($conn));
    }
```

It is gives warning when i am trying to insert data into database.

Please help me for solve this warning.

Comment: Would like to see how did you extend your connection file

Comment: include_once './connection.php';       i extends my connection file as like this.

Comment: you need to use return statement. and store it somewhere in $conn variable,

Comment: Your `function connect()` creates a connection, but since it does not return the connection, it is out of scope. You need to append `return $connection;` in the function, and then when you do `$conn = connect();` you will have the returned connection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return `$connection` so that it will not be undefined in `global $connection;`:

```
function connect(){
    $server = "localhost";
    $user = "xxxx";
    $password = "xxxx";
    $db = "xxxx";
    $connection = mysqli_connect($server,$user,$password,$db);
    return $connection; // return $connection
}
```

**Note**: You spelled `$connection` wrongly, should not be `$connetion`.

Comment: `$conn` is not defined in the function, but `$connection` is.

Comment: I also did it but it gives me same warning of Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given.

Comment: @ShahAnkit Try echoing `$connection`

Comment: Thanks sir now it work and data is inserted in database.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return connection object from the function `connect`.

```
function connect(){
        $server = "localhost";
        $user = "xxxx";
        $password = "xxxx";
        $db = "xxxx";
        $connection = mysqli_connect($server,$user,$password,$db);
        return $connection; // return connection object
}
```